# Pathing Issue when Executing Airflow run & backfill commands on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

**Verions**

- Airflow: 1.10.7
- Kubernetes: 1.14.9

**Setup**

Airflow is configured to use Kubernetes Executors; Normal operations work just fine;

Dags and logs are accessed via EFS volumes defined with `PersistentVolume` & `PersistentVolumeClaim` specs ;

I have the following k8s spec, which I want to run backfill jobs with;

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: backfill-test
  namespace: airflow
spec:
  serviceAccountName: airflow-service-account
  volumes:
    - name: airflow-dags
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: airflow-dags
    - name: airflow-logs
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: airflow-logs
  containers:
  - name: somename
    image: myimage
    volumeMounts:
    - name: airflow-dags
      mountPath: /usr/local/airflow/dags
      readOnly: true
    - name: airflow-logs
      mountPath: /usr/local/airflow/logs
      readOnly: false
    env:
    - name: AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR
      value: KubernetesExecutor
    - name: AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__NAMESPACE
      value: airflow
    - name: AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_FOLDER
      value: dags
    - name: AIRFLOW__CORE__BASE_LOG_FOLDER
      value: logs
    # - name: AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__DAGS_VOLUME_MOUNT_POINT
    #   value: /usr/local/airflow/dags
    - name: AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__DAGS_VOLUME_SUBPATH
      value: dags
    - name: AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__LOGS_VOLUME_SUBPATH
      value: logs
    - name: AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__DAGS_VOLUME_CLAIM
      value: airflow-dags
    - name: AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__LOGS_VOLUME_CLAIM
      value: airflow-logs
    - name: AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__WORKER_CONTAINER_REPOSITORY
      value: someimage_uri
    - name: AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__WORKER_CONTAINER_TAG
      value: latest
    - name: AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__WORKER_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME
      value: airflow-service-account
    - name: AIRFLOW_HOME
      value: usr/local/airflow

    # command: ["sleep", "1h"]


    command: ["airflow", "backfill", 
              "my_dag",
    #           # "--subdir", ".",
    #           "--local",
              "--task_regex", "my_task_task",
              "--start_date", "2020-07-01T00:00:00",
              "--end_date", "2020-08-01T00:00:00"]
  restartPolicy: Never
```

**Problem**

The issue with this seems to be some pathing problem when the task is added to the queue

When running the initial command, the cli finds the dag and associated task;

```
airflow@backfill-test:~$ airflow run my_dag my_task 2020-07-01T01:15:00+00:00 --local --raw --force
```

```
[2020-08-27 23:14:42,038] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor KubernetesExecutor
[2020-08-27 23:14:42,040] {dagbag.py:403} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags
Running %s on host %s <TaskInstance: my_dag.my_task 2020-07-01T01:15:00+00:00 [failed]> backfill-test
```

However, the task gets added to the queue with some weird path. Log of the actual task execution attempt below.

```
[2020-08-27 23:14:43,019] {taskinstance.py:867} INFO - Starting attempt 3 of 2
[2020-08-27 23:14:43,019] {taskinstance.py:868} INFO -
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-08-27 23:14:43,043] {taskinstance.py:887} INFO - Executing <Task(PostgresOperator): my_task> on 2020-07-01T01:15:00+00:00
[2020-08-27 23:14:43,046] {standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 191 to run task
[2020-08-27 23:14:43,085] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-08-27 23:14:43,085] {dagbag.py:403} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags/usr/local/airflow/my_dag.py
[2020-08-27 23:14:53,006] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-08-27 23:14:53,006] {local_task_job.py:103} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

Adding `--subdir` to the initial command doesn't actually get propagated to the task queue, and results in the same log output.